# save file without save file dialog in c# webbrowser control

Tags: c#, winforms, browser, download, savefiledialog

I am implementing code to automatic download files from client site without  manual step using *C#* code.

My requirement is to save the files through *C#* code by passing path without save file dialog.

This is code to show the *Save file dialog* when click on *Download* button in *C#* window *WebBrowser* control .

```
 foreach (HtmlElement row in webBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames["View_Frame"].Document.GetElementsByTagName("input"))
                        {
                            if (row.Name == "DOWNLOADALL")
                            {
                                row.InvokeMember("click");
                                tbState.Text = "4";
                                break;
                            }

                        }
```

Comment: Please be more careful about formatting next time.

Comment: This has been solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538874/suppressing-the-save-open-dialog-box-in-a-webbrowser-control/69577989#69577989

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this that would not show any dialog for download:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
foreach (HtmlElement row in webBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames["View_Frame"].Document.GetElementsByTagName("input"))
  {
    if (row.Name == "DOWNLOADALL")
      {
        row.InvokeMember("click");
        tbState.Text = "4";
        client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
        client.DownloadFile(URL, path);//I don't know where is your URL and path!
        break;
      }

 }
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8597407/suppress-save-dialog-in-web-browser-and-automate-the-download)

Comment: i Try this but downloaded path file contain HTML tag and some related text which is not actual text of file to download.

Comment: @MaiHuNa Did it download file with extra texts?

Comment: @MaiHuNa It seems file that you want to download needs login first. test my code with another file that don't need login.

Comment: i need to download files after login its my requirement

Comment: i used this but not work client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");